# Problems extending core review block helper

Tags: blocks, review, helper, extend

I'm trying to extend the review block helper located at `/app/code/core/core/Mage/Review/Block/Helper.php`. I've created a new module at `/app/code/local/MyModule/Review/Block/Helper.php` which includes and extends the parent class as follows:

```
include('Mage/Review/Block/Helper.php');

class Mymodule_Review_Block_Helper extends Mage_Review_Block_Helper
{
```

I've also created a config.xml file at app/code/local/Mymodule/etc/config.xml which contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
       <Mymodule>
            <version&gt;1.0.1</version>
       <;/Mymodule>
   </modules>
   <global>
      <blocks>
       <review>
         <rewrite>
           <mage_review_block_helper>Mymodule_Review_Block_Helper</mage_review_block_helper>
         </rewrite>
        </review>
      </blocks>
   </global>
</config>
```

However, any method changes that I drop into my file I not being implemented on the front end, with or without flushing the cache.

I suspect it's something as simple as the keys in the XML not being correct but I can't work out what that correct nesting should be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config.xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
       <Mymodule>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
       </Mymodule>
   </modules>
   <global>
      <blocks>
       <review>
         <rewrite>
           <helper>Mymodule_Review_Block_Helper</helper>
         </rewrite>
        </review>
      </blocks>
   </global>
</config>
```

and you can remove `include('Mage/Review/Block/Helper.php');` from your class file. It will be autoloaded when needed.

Comment: Thanks, bit of a noob with this Magento lark.  Great help!

Answer (score 2):

there are lot of issue in your module

1.for block type rewrite ,you donot need to add Parent class in include path.

```
include('Mage/Review/Block/Helper.php'); Just remove it
```

2.Rewrite  code is wrong.

```
<mage_review_block_helper>Mymodule_Review_Block_Helper</mage_review_block_helper>
```

should be

```
<helper>Mymodule_Review_Block_Helper</helper>
```

3.Your module declarationn  in config.xml wrong:

```
 <modules>
       <Mymodule>
            <version&gt;1.0.1</version>
       <;/Mymodule>
   </modules>
```

should be

```
<modules>
       <Mymodule_Review>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
       </Mymodule_Review>
   </modules>
```